# Date strings not working in date range select statement

Tags: oracle, date, coldfusion

I'm having an issue with a couple of dates which is eluding me at the moment.

I have 2 date strings in the following format: `dd-mm-yyyy`. So for example

- DATE1 = `10-03-2013`
- DATE2 = `15-03-2013`

I need to use these dates in the following query:

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="#getDSN()#">
        SELECT      
            DOCUMENT_NUMBER
        FROM
            MY TABLE            
        WHERE
            DATE_ORDER_ENTER 
        BETWEEN 
            <cfqueryparam value="#DATE1#"  maxlength="10">
        AND
            <cfqueryparam value="#DATE2#" maxlength="10">                   
    </cfquery>
```

The problem I am having is converting these date strings to actual dates. I am finding the month and day are swapping around. I have tried functions like `createODBCDate()` to see if that cured the problem, but it is still not working. Does anyone have a solution?

I am using CF9.01 and Oracle 10g.

Many thanks,
JC

Comment: My Oracle knowledge is slim at best so sorry if I'm way off but try adding: ALTER SESSION 
SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'; before your select.

Comment: Pass parameters as strings like '31/12/2000' and convert them into dates **inside your query**: `between to_date('31/12/2000','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('31/12/2001','dd/mm/yyyy')`

Comment: ParseDateTime or LSParseDateTime should convert your date string to a date object

Comment: Once you use the functions mentioned by @duncan, add cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" to your cfqueryparam tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am finding the month and day are swapping around. I have tried
>   functions like createodbcdate() to see if this will cure the problem
>   but still not working.

The standard CF date functions like CreateODBCDate, ParseDateTime, etecetera **always** use [English (U.S.) date formatting conventions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7843.html). So the date string `10-03-2013` will **always** be treated as October 3rd. You get lucky with non-ambiguous date strings like `15-03-2012`. Obviously there no month 15, so CF automatically swaps them. That is why it *seems* to work with some non-US date strings, but not others.

To parse locale sensitive dates, use the `LSxxxxx` date functions as @duncan suggested. Ignoring validation, something like this:

```
   <cfset dateObject = LSParseDateTime("10/03/2013", "pt_PT")>
```

Note, according to the documentation the [dashes ie dd-mm-yyyy are NOT standard](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e12.html) in most other locales. Apparently only in Dutch(Standard) and Portuguese (Standard).

Also, be sure to add the correct date type to `cfqueryparam` as @Dan suggested. Otherwise, it will default to type `char` and may cause a syntax error.

Comment: Thankyou for the example.I have looked at the documentation for LSParseDateTime() function. In your example use use pt_PT. What does the pt_PT do to the string as i couldnt find any reference to it in the docs?

Comment: It is string representing a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). The first part is the language code: `pt`. The second half is the country code: `PT`. So `pt_PT` represents what CF calls "Portugal (Standard)" . I think CF still accepts that string too. Though personally, I try and stay away from using the old CF locale strings because they are non-standard.

Comment: Here is a little more [documentation on locales](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-67f2.html). Though it mostly points you to the old javadocs (surprise, surprise): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html

Comment: *what CF calls "Portugal (Standard)"* Drat. That should read " Portuguese (Standard)". Darn five minute edit limit..

Comment: man I should have recognised the pt_PT as a locale, feel a little silly now as i use locales all of the time though not the Portugal one :). Just testing all of this so far so good.

Comment: Haha, no worries. You could also parse it yourself like Dan suggested, and throw in a some validation to boot. Either way works.

Answer (score 1):

Not as slick as Leigh's answer, but this should also work.

```
dateString = "10-03-2013";  // March 10 2013
dateObj = CreateDate(   ListLast(dateString, "-")
                        , ListGetAt(dateString, 2, "-")
                        , ListFirst(dateString, "-")
                    );
```

In other words, treat your string as a hyphen delimted list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following function to create date:

```
CreateDate(year, month, day)
```

and use the following function to format it according to your need

```
DateFormat("date" [, "mask" ])
```