# ColdFusion - DateFormat invert the date on refresh page

Tags: coldfusion, date-format

I have a cfm page with a textbox that has inside a date.
The default date is `"Now()"` and I can edit it. 
In the same page I have some "combobox" that refresh the page when I change the selection. The issue is if I write inside the textbox, for example, `"01/05/2013"` after the refresh there will be `"05/01/2013"` and after another refresh there will be `"01/05/2013"`.
Here some code:

```
<cfset myDate="">
<cfif isDefined('URL.date') and URL.date neq "">
<cfset myDate="#DateFormat(URL.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')#">
<cfelse>
<cfset myDate="#DateFormat(Now(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')#">
</cfif>
<cfoutput>
<cfinput type="text" name="date" id="date" style="width:65px; text-align:center" class="input" value="#myDate#">
</cfoutput>
```

EDIT:
on javascript I use to save the date the following code:

```
var date=document.getElementById("date");
```

and I refresh the page with:

```
location.href("myPage.cfm?date="+date.value);
```

any help? Thanks.

Comment: are you "refreshing" or "resubmitting"?

Comment: i use location.href so i reload the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Travis stated, by default ColdFusion treats dates with the U.S. format `mm/dd/yyyy`. So your example of `01/05/2013` translates to January 5, 2013.  Then you re-format that date into `dd/mm/yyyy` format as `05/01/2013`.  Your JavaScript then assigns this new date to your form field. On resubmission the date is now `05/01/2013` which in US format is May 1, 2013. Then you reformat back to `01/05/2013` and JavaScript updates your form field, and so on.

Since you are wanting to deal with a non-U.S. date format you should use the Locale Specific `LSDateFormat()` function instead of `DateFormat()`. With it you can specify a format and locale to use.

```
lsDateFormat( myDate, "dd/mm/yyyy", "en_GB")
```

Comment: Lol, I said June.  #1 reason you shouldn't program with a migraine.

Comment: This must be one of the most commonly misunderstood behaviors in CF ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557244/coldfusion-10-dateformat-issue/16569306#16569306 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929492/date-strings-not-working-in-date-range-select-statement/15932634#15932634 , etcetera ...

Comment: Yep, we do seem to get quite a few of these questions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because CF wants to use Month/Day/Year format by default.  When you type 1/5/13 CF thinks you mean Jan 5, 2013, so when you use `dateformat` to format it to day/month/year you get 5/1/2013, when the page is reloaded with 5/1/2013, CF now thinks you mean May 1, 2013. Each time you reload the page it swaps it back and forth.

If you don't want ColdFusion messing with your date that you input, don't apply the `dateFormat` Adobe docs for [`dateFormat`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_29.html) suggests formatting dates on input is a bad idea.

> **Note:** The DateFormat function is best used for formatting output, not
>   for formatting input. For formatting input, use one of the date/time
>   creation functions (for example, CreateDate) instead.

Answer (score 0):

url.date is not a date object, it's a string.  Therefore this line:

```
<cfset myDate="#DateFormat(URL.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')#">
```

is overengineered.   All you need is:

```
<cfset myDate = URL.date>
```

This simple change should solve your problem.

Comment: @gabboSonc can you include a full repro case?